# Rendering Child Component from store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a component which has child components, i want to render these child components with different Ids. They are getting their data from store.The problem is they are rendered but with the same item. how can this be solved?

**MultiImages Component**

```
const MultiImages: () => JSX.Element = () => {
  const values = ['500', '406', '614'];

  return ( 
      <div>
        {values.map((val, index) => {
          return <OneImage key={index} projectID={val} />;
        })}
      </div>
  );
};

export default MultiImages;
```

**OneImage Component**

```
const OneImage: () => JSX.Element = ({ projectID }) => {
  const projectData = useProjectDataStore();
  const { getProject } = useAction();
  useEffect(() => {
    getProject(projectID ?? '');
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div> 
            <img
              src={projectData.picture}
              }
            />
          <div>
            <a>
              {projectData.projectName}
            </a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default OneImage;
```

Comment: can you try this syntax `getProject(pojectID &&  pojectID )`. log the projectID and make sure you receiving projectID from other end .

Comment: Its not really clear what does your getProject() do, and what are you doing with projectData, but seems that you are fetching something with getProject, so all your images will be the last from the list.

Comment: @AlexShtromberg do you know how to solve that?

Comment: I think you should share `useProjectDataStore` logic as well, it's hard to tell how you get `projectData` from that function @NewDev

Comment: @NewDev can you confirm that you are loading images with "getProject" and "useProjectDataStore" fetches latest result from your store and I(or anyone who read the message first) will right you an answer here. Right now its only guesses.

Comment: @AlexShtromberg yes that's true

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here - you are calling in a loop, one by one fetch your projects, and each call, as far as we can understand from your example and comments override each other.

Your are doing it implicitly, cause your fetching functionality is inside your Item Component **OneImage**

In general, the way you are using global state and trying to isolate one from another nodes is nice, you need to think about your selector hook.

I suggest you, to prevent rewriting too many parts of the code, to change a bit your selector "useProjectDataStore" and make it depended on "projectID".

Each load of next project with **getProject** might store into your global state result, but instead of overriding ALL the state object, you might want to use Map(Dictionary) as a data structure, and write a result there and use projectID as a key.

So, in your code the only place what might be change is OneImage component

```
const OneImage: () => JSX.Element = ({ projectID }) => {
  // making your hook depended on **projectID**
  const projectData = useProjectDataStore(projectID);
  const { getProject } = useAction();
  useEffect(() => {
    // No need of usage **projectID** cause it will inherit if from useProjectDataStore
    getProject();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div> 
            <img
              src={projectData.picture}
              }
            />
          <div>
            <a>
              {projectData.projectName}
            </a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default OneImage;
```

And inside of your useProjectDataStore store result into a specific key using projectID.

Answer (score 0):

Your component `OneImage` will return what's in the return statement, in your case:

```
<>
  <div> 
    <img
      src={projectData.picture}
    />
    <div>
      <a>
        {projectData.projectName}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</>
```

This tag `<></>` around your element is a React.fragment and has no key. This is the reason you get this error.
Since you already have a div tag wrapping your element you can do this:

```
<div key={parseInt(projectID)}> 
  <img
    src={projectData.picture}
  />
  <div>
    <a>
      {projectData.projectName}
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also change the key to `Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999)`.
Note that passing the prop `key={index}` is unnecessary, and is not advised to use index as keys in a react list.

Comment: The issue here is unrelated to key. Also, your suggestion is exactly what written in official documentation as ["wrong solution"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys).